# Geometric Series question

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could someone give me a hint on how I could do this question( it is a non- calculator question):

The 5th term of a geometric series is 12 and the 7th term is 3. Find the two possible values of the sum to infinity of the series

Comment: Common ratio = $\pm \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a,r$ be the first term and the common ratio respectively,

$ar^{5-1}=12, ar^{7-1}=3\implies r^2=\dfrac14$

The [infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence) sum $=\dfrac a{1-r}$

Comment: But its a geometric series right. Dont we have to equate the 12 to u1(r^5-1)/(r-1)?

Comment: @Maths2468, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Elementary_properties and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series

Answer (score 4):

Let the first term be $a$ and the common ratio be $r$.

Then,
$$ar^4=12$$
$$ar^6=3$$
Dividing the two,
$$r^2\frac14$$
$$r=\pm\frac12$$

Using this, the sum can be found.

Comment: But its a geometric series right. Dont we have to equate the 12 to u1(r^5-1)/(r-1)?

Comment: @Maths2468 That is the sum of the first five terms of the geometric series. The fifth term of the series will be the term of the corresponding sequence.

Comment: oh that makes the question far far easier! I thought the word series was only used when a sequence was being added.

Comment: @Maths2468: Yes, "series" generally implies the sum of a sequence, but not always. IMHO, the wording of that question is sloppy for using the word  "series" like that. It should say "geometric sequence" or "geometric progression". Feel free to deduct half a mark from your teacher. :)

Comment: @Maths2468 If not for the sequence, "term" of a series would make little sense. A series is a formal sum of its terms. What you referred to was the 5th partial sum of the series.